# What is the structure of the data returned when grouping on the server in a Telerik Kendo Grid

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid

I have a telerik Kendo Grid that is using an ajax Data source, that calls a aspnet MVC Endpoint. I'm doing both sorting and paging on the server side and it all works great.

I now want to implement server side grouping.

My Question how should the data being returned from my mvc endpoint be structured.

For example I currently return json data like

```
{
"total": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "RealAssetId": 2,
        "Building": "Building2",
        "Level": "Level2",
        "Zone": "Zone2",
        "Room": "Room2",
        "AssetId": "Asset Id2",
        "AssetCategory": "Asset Gategory2",
        "AssetFamily": "Asset Family2",
        "AssetType": "Asset Type2"
    },
    {
        "RealAssetId": 3,
        "Building": "Building2",
        "Level": "Level3",
        "Zone": "Zone3",
        "Room": "Room3",
        "AssetId": "Asset  Id3",
        "AssetCategory": "Asset Gategory3",
        "AssetFamily": "Asset Family3",
        "AssetType": "Asset Type3"
    }
]
```

}

with a schema on my data source like

```
 schema: {
            data: "data",
            total: "total",                
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Building: { editable: false },
                    Level: { editable: false },
                    Zone: { editable: false },
                    Room: { editable: false },
                    AssetId: { editable: false },
                    AssetCategory: { editable: false },
                    AssetFamily: { editable: false },
                    AssetType: { editable: false }                                            }
            }
        }
```

How should my data/schema be structured if I was grouping by "building".

**Additional Information From Comments.**

My Controller method looks like this

```
public ActionResult GetDataTasks(int skip, int take, int page, int pageSize, List<SortDto> sort = null, List<GroupDTO> group = null, FilterSetDTO filter = null)
```

All the paging, sorting, grouping data gets serialised into the input methods fine. I gather the data from my database using entity framework.

Sorting is done via linq

```
 if (sort != null && sort.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var s in sort)
                {
                    dataTasks = dataTasks.OrderBy(s.field + " " + s.dir);
                }
            }
```

As well as paging,

```
dataTasks.Skip(skip).Take(take)).ToList()
```

I'm not entirely sure how I am going to implement the grouping yet, but first of all I need to work out what shape the return data should be.

For example do I need to structure the return data like

```
{
"total": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "Building": "Building2",
        "Data": [
            {
                "RealAssetId": 2,
                "Level": "Level2",
                "Zone": "Zone2",
                "Room": "Room2",
                "AssetId": "Asset Id2",
                "AssetCategory": "Asset Gategory2",
                "AssetFamily": "Asset Family2",
                "AssetType": "Asset Type2"
            },
            {
                "Level": "Level3",
                "Zone": "Zone3",
                "Room": "Room3",
                "AssetId": "Asset  Id3",
                "AssetCategory": "Asset Gategory3",
                "AssetFamily": "Asset Family3",
                "AssetType": "Asset Type3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: take a look at this within the documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-group, essentially return the data as you currently do but just provide the `entry point` for the grouping category i.e. `AssetFamily` for example. If you need a full example then I can provide a dojo (although this will show it from using client side)

Comment: Thanks @DavidShorthose. But wouldn't that just be client side grouping. I want to do the grouping within my C# Controller. Then the grid just has to display the data without manipulating it. Is what I'm asking possible?

Comment: How are you doing the server paging and sorting, is this custom or is it using the DataSourceRequest class? If you want the visual indicator of the grouping then you need to provide the datasource as you currently have and then add the `group` element in your returned datasource. Providing you are sending this back to the server. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverGrouping (details about server grouping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found some more information here

http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.groups

and

http://www.telerik.com/forums/datasource-remote-grouping

The data needs to be structured like

```
{
"total": 2,
"groups": {
    "field": "Building",
    "value": "Smith Tower",
    "aggregates": [],
    "items": [
        {
            "RealAssetId": 1,
            "Building": "Smith Tower",
            "Level": "Level",
            "Zone": "Zone",
            "Room": "Room",
            "AssetId": "Asset Id",
            "AssetCategory": "Asset Gategory",
            "AssetFamily": "Asset Family",
            "AssetType": "Asset Type"
        },
        {
            "RealAssetId": 2,
            "Building": "Smith Tower",
            "Level": "Level3",
            "Zone": "Zone3",
            "Room": "Room3",
            "AssetId": "Asset  Id3",
            "AssetCategory": "Asset Gategory3",
            "AssetFamily": "Asset Family3",
            "AssetType": "Asset Type3"  
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

It important to include the empty aggregates collection. Kendo throws an exception other wise.

With the data source schema like

```
 schema: {
        groups: "groups",
        total: "total",                
        model: {
            fields: {
                Building: { editable: false },
                Level: { editable: false },
                Zone: { editable: false },
                Room: { editable: false },
                AssetId: { editable: false },
                AssetCategory: { editable: false },
                AssetFamily: { editable: false },
                AssetType: { editable: false }                                            }
        }
    }
```